# Laravel migrations messed up

Tags: laravel-4, database-migration, command-line-interface

I meesed up my Laravel migrations and I get PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare Class when running

`php artisan migrate --path="workbench/fefe/feeds2go/src/migrations"`

I have been deleting the migration file and dropping manually the table and recreated with `php artisan migrate:make` but still the same.

How can I fix migratons?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to check all of your migration class files and check for duplicate class names.

Comment: Is it possible to get this error in laravel when you don't have other migrations with this same class name?

Comment: @JoshR., yes it's possible. try composer dump-autoload and see if it works. reference: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/8782#issuecomment-145324891

Answer (score 0):

> "Cannot redeclare class" happens when the class name appears at least
>   2 times.

The easiest way to do it is to run either `composer install` or `composer.phar dump-autoload`. It will generate warning information for you to identify which class is duplicated. Then, simply remove the class that declared twice.

Here is the error I got after I ran php artisan migrate

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]   
Cannot redeclare class CreateKidTimeslotTable
```

Therefore, I use `composer.phar dump-autoload` to identify the error.

```
 Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "CreateKidTimeslotTable" was found in both "laravel/database/migrations/2016_05_23_024341_create_kid_timeslot_table.php" and "laravel/database/migrations/2016_08_24_022635_create_kid_time_slot_table.php", the first will be used.
```

Remove the duplicated table that you don't need anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete that migration file manually from the migration directory of your project and also, delete it's entry from the migration table in the database or you can run the `php artisan migrate:refresh` but it will drop your all table data so also add the your step with `php artisan migrate:refresh --step=n`

Answer (score -1):

This is a late answer, but probably this would solve your issue.

1. Go to `app/storage/migrations`.
2. Delete the migration file that causes the error (You can also delete everything stored there).
3. Done.